# C++ -- Dynamic brace Initialization of a 2D array of *var[2] with class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, syntax

: edit:

Paul McKenzie in the comments suggested an alternative way to accomplish this that I have since adopted. I am still leaving this question open for the purposes of curiosity in case anyone knows how to initialize the object as described below. Thank you very much for your time, and patience.

: end edit :

I have a straightforward `quadtree::Vector2` template with two members, `"".x` and `"".y`. I'm trying to create a dynamic 2D array of shape [][2]. Where the first index will be determined at runtime, and I'm trying to place the resulting object into a

`std::map<int, quadtree::Vector2<int> *[2]> animations`

variable. Basically, the animations map maps enumerated integer values that refer to specific spritesheet animations to an array of point pairs that determine the texture rectangle for each frame of the animation on the spritesheet.

Now that the context is out of the way, my initialization code is as follows:

```
    quadtree::Vector2<int> *idle[2] = new quadtree::Vector2<int>[4][2] = {
        {quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*0, 48*0), quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*1, 48*1) },
        {quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*1, 48*0), quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*2, 48*1) },
        {quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*2, 48*0), quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*3, 48*1) },
        {quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*3, 48*0), quadtree::Vector2<int>(48*4, 48*1) },           
    };
```

Thing is, I'm definitely sure this is not actually how to do it. And sure enough, upon compilation, I get:

```
entity.cpp:31:46: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   31 |         quadtree::Vector2<int> *idle[2] = & (new quadtree::Vector2<int>[4][2] = {
```

And I'm sure all sorts of other errors further down the line as a result of this. I've tried looking at other 2D array initialization questions, but they usually are for basic dynamic 2D initialization of integers and/or brace initialization of simpler data-types. And I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. I feel like it's something straightforward, but that isn't easy to see unless you really have experience with unusual (e.g. jank) data structures, lol.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: *I'm trying to create a dynamic 2D array of shape [][2]* -- Have you tried something like this instead: `std::vector<std::array<quadtree::Vector2<int>, 2>>`?  That basically spells out what you are attempting to do:  A dynamic array of an array of 2 `Vector2<int>`'s.

Comment: Ah! Let me try that right quick and see if it works. Sounds very simple. Duh. But if it does work, I think I'll still keep this question open just for the increase in knowledge gained by learning how to do it that way.

Comment: You also won't need `new`.  You could initialize the entire vector with those 4 items using the brace initializer.

Comment: I use new because the initialized variable is passed out of scope and stored as a pointer. Also, while using a std::vector works, the initialized variables don't change at all once they've been created, so maybe using nested std::arrays would work. But then, each created array has variable length for the first index, so may I ask how you would do this with a std::array of a std::array?

Comment: Arrays are fixed in size.  They cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: Try what @PaulMcKenzie suggested first. You could also make the initialization simpler. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/5P8Yo5zGK)

Comment: All right. I've tried what @PaulMcKenzie suggested first, Ted Lyngmo, and both of you are right. It worked out well, and I was easily able to add the new() for out of scope access. Thank you, both of you, and I'm sorry I doubted you, Paul. I guess in the long run, trying to use nested arrays of arrays is a classic case of over-optimization, lol. I'll be using your method instead. :D

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding "_I was easily able to add the `new()` for out of scope access_" - Don't. Return the `idle` object from your function instead (or move it into a container if you wish). You nearly never need `new`/`delete` or `new[]`/`delete[]` - and that's a good thing because passing bare pointers between parts of your program _will_ lead to a lot of problems. A `vector` deals with the memory management internally so you don't have to. See Paul's answer. No bare pointers.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a `std::vector` of a `std::array<quadtree::Vector2<int>>`.

Some `using` syntax makes this a little  more clear:

```
using QuadTree2 = std::array<quadTree::Vector2<int>, 2>;
using QuadTreeVector = std::vector<QuadTree2>;
using QuadTreeMap = std::map<int, QuadTreeVector>;
```

After that, then the initialization could be done like this:

```
QuadTreeVector idle = {
        {{{48*0, 48*0}, {48*1, 48*1}}},
        {{{48*1, 48*0}, {48*2, 48*1}}},
        {{{48*2, 48*0}, {48*3, 48*1}}},
        {{{48*3, 48*0}, {48*4, 48*1}}},
    };

QuadTreeMap theMap;
//...
theMap.insert({1,idle});
```

Comment: Maybe even `theMap.emplace(1, std::move(idle));`